# Frequency of updates on Google Streetview?

Tags: google-maps

In February & April, there was a break in. I've tried to use Google Maps Streetview to try and get an idea of suspects. Unfortunately, it only shows the streeview from 2014 and I was wondering if there was another way of getting these images.

Comment: Streetviews are updated only as often as the Google cars drive around neighborhoods, which, as you surmised from the date on the images, is not very often.  They are not generated by any other means, as far as I know.

Comment: Check CCTV of local businesses? There is no service on earth which real time monitors your house as this would be a massive privacy issue and expensive for no purpose. (Exclusions include if you are the target of an intelligence service like the CIA)

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to hear about your situation. While disappointing that you do not have images of the timeframe you'd like, perhaps understand its purpose will soften your frustration. Google's Streetview seeks to provide "travelers" with a visual approximation what the areas being traveled may look like. It is not intended to give a "read-time" representation of roads. "Real-time," of course, is relative, but as you've noticed, it can be years before the images are updated. The frequency of update is up to Google, but may be influenced by the popularity of the area traveled and/or whether significant changes have occurred to the area.